# Why is jshint throwing an error when i declare a class field?

Tags: javascript, jshint

There is an `App` class in the app:

```
  class App {
      static cart;
      static init() {
        const shop = new Shop();
        shop.render();
        this.cart = shop.cart;
      }
    }
```

I'm using `VSCode` as IDE and `jshint` as a code quality tool.
Declaring of `static cart;` as an `App` class field  causes the next error message in `Problems panel`:

```
(property) App.cart: any
Class properties must be methods. Expected '(' but instead saw ';'. (E054)jshint(E054)
```

I tried to google for this problem, but failed.
Could you tell, please, what i am doing wrong? 
I'm new to JS, so maybe there is a syntax error in my code?

Comment: That's an *experimental* feature, it's not yet part of the language, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields. I don't know how, but you may need some configuration to tell JSHint you're using non-standard language features.

Comment: …or even better, just don't use that language feature here. No reason to make `App` a `class` with only static properties. Use an object literal instead. Or even plain `let cart; function init() { … }`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what your code is supposed to be doing (e.g. I don't know what `Shop` is/does), but I can tell you that class field definitions [are allowed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#prod-FieldDefinition) and are no longer experimental [as of ES2022 spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/main/finished-proposals.md).

I believe this is bug / limitation in the current version of `jshint` (v2.13.4 at the time of this writing) in that it does not yet recognize [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). See https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/3139, which tracks the issue.

Unfortunately for the project, JSHint has had a hard time keeping pace with other tools in recent years. As described [here](http://mikepennisi.com/blog/2020/you-may-finally-use-jshint-for-evil/) by one of the maintainers, this was at least partly due to its clever and humorous but surprisingly problematic license agreement.

See also:

- https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/11/18/ecmacscript-static-fields.html
- https://deliciousinsights.github.io/confoo-es2022/#/class-novelties